Import Script and Convert HTML, JS and CSS Code To Run In Laravel
I have a laravel project and I want to run a html, js and css code in the laravel blade frontend but am running into some issues. I am new to laravel and moving from angular and nodejs so my apology in advance if this is a basic question.
I want to get a hosted IFrame sample from clover to work on my laravel project. The IFrame project in reference can be found here. I have done extensive research as well as found and tried a lot of solutions but none seem to solve my problem.
I am trying to add the component in a checkout blade file. The issue I am running into are:

The script in the html tag is not being processed by laravel.
I am Unable to link and get the field and functionality working for binding the elements.

I have tried putting the js and cs files in the corresponding folder in the public directory, /public/css/checkout.css and /public/js/checkout.js. But the scripts are failing to load.
The blade file I am adding the code to contains the following code with HTML I added for the form from the iframe example.
@if ($userBe->is_checkout_login == 1)
            <div class="payment-options">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/checkout.css') }}">
                <script src="{{ asset('js/checkout.js') }}"></script>
                <script src="https://checkout.sandbox.dev.clover.com/sdk.js"></script>
                <h4 class="mb-4">Checkout</h4>
                <head>
                    <title>GPay and Hosted Checkout</title>
                </head>
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
                        <div class="form-row top-row">
                            <div id="payment-request-button" class="payment-request-button full-width"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hr">
                      <span>
                        Or Pay with Card
                      </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row top-row">
                            <div id="card-number" class="field full-width"></div>
                            <div class="input-errors" id="card-number-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div id="card-date" class="field third-width"></div>
                            <div class="input-errors" id="card-date-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div id="card-cvv" class="field third-width"></div>
                            <div class="input-errors" id="card-cvv-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div id="card-postal-code" class="field third-width"></div>
                            <div class="input-errors" id="card-postal-code-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

                        <!-- Testing -->
                        <div id="card-response" role="alert"></div>
                        <div class="button-container">
                            <button>Submit Payment</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="placeorder-button mt-4">
                <button class="main-btn w-100" type="button" form="payment" id="placeOrderBtn">
                <span class="btn-title">
                    {{ $keywords['Place Order'] ?? __('Place Order') }}
                </span>
                </button>
            </div>
</div>
@endif

When running this code, the current output of the page is shown in the image below and no errors occur but I can tell the scripts arnt loaded because the binding and clover scripts are not being applied to the component and page: 
I have tried a couple of solutions including this:
The above mentioned did not work and was unclear. <script type="text/javascript" {!! \Helper::cspNonceAttr() !!}> returns helper not found and adding it to the environment doesnt load the script.
Nothing seems to work as I have tried multiple other suggestions and solutions. Am I doing it wrong or possibly missing something?

What relevant errors are you seeing in the console? Is the iframe url and the main page hosted on the same domain?

I am not getting errors and the output image is added to the post. The IFrame I referenced was a codesandbox example from clover on how to use their hosted IFrame. It works fine on our other project that is written in js but I cannot get it to load and work on the laravel project.

So they are not hosted on the same domain as one is a local laravel project and the other is a js code sample that I am trying to import over to php laravel.

Putting a head and title element somewhere into a div, makes little sense to begin with. "but I can tell the scripts arnt loaded because" - don't draw premature conclusions. Verify whether the scripts were actually loaded or not, using the dev tools network panel.

Yea, i initially didnt copy those over but wanted to try putting the scripts in the head to see if that leads to them loading. I did check the developer tools and the locally added script work fine but ther external clover script is not loaded shown or rendered.

I get the error now it is: Clover is not defined which is due to the clover sdk script not loading. If that loaded then this issue should be resolved. That is what makes me think that the external script not loading is the issue.

The general recommendation is to load the CSS files in the <head> portion of the HTML and load the scripts at the end of the <body> because if a script relies on HTML elements to work then you need to load the script after those elements have been loaded. In Laravel if you're using some boilerplate layout then it should come with stacks that you could leverage for this. Also I suspect you need to load the clover script before your checkout script to ensure that clover is available for your own script

I am not quite sure where the head is located in the laravel project as in angular and other js frameworks, we can import it directly into the index.html file. Can you specify where the head tag is to add the script?
Also, I tried with stacks but was unclear and confused about it. Can you describe a bit more on how I can use that stack(). Do I have to initialize it first or can I just start using it? Plus, what is the string inside the stack(). ex: In @stack('scripts') what is scripts? Do I replace script with something else? Finally, what is the difference between @push() and @stack()

Although the @stack() and @Push() did not work, I resolved the issue with a section script and @IncludeIf. The order of scripts also seems to be important. My Code is:
@section('script')
    <script src="https://checkout.sandbox.dev.clover.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/css/clover-checkout.css') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/clover-checkout.js') }}"></script>
    @includeIf($userBe->is_checkout == 1);
@endsection

